# How to calculate the quality of clustering by dtw?

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis, distance

my aim is to cluster 126 time-series concerning 26 weeks (so each time-series has 26 observation). I used `pam{cluster}` = partitioning around medoids to cluster these time-series.

Before clustering I wanted to compare which distance measure is the most appropriate: euclidean, manhattan or dynamic time warping. I used each distance to cluster and compare by silhouette plot. Is there any way I can compare different distance measure?

For example I know that procedure `clValid {clValid}` to validate cluster results, however I cannot implement dtw to calculate indexes.

So how can I compare different distance metrics (not only by silhouette)?

Additional question: is GAP statistic enough to decide how many clusters choose? Or should I evaluate number of clusters with different methods or compare two or three ways how to do it?

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have just read the book "cluster analysis, fifth edition" by Brian S. Everitt, etc. And currently, I adopt the following strategy to select method to calculate distance matrix, clustering and validation:

for distance: using `cmdscale{stats}` function to calculate multidimentional scaling, and plot the scatterplot of the two scaling dimensions with density information. As expected, if there is distinct clusters or nested clusters, the scatterplot will give some hints.

for clustering: for every clustering method, calculate cophenetic correlation between clustering results and the distance, this can be calculated using `cophenetic{stats}` function. The best clustering method will give higher correlation. However, this is only working for hierarchical clustering. I haven't idea for other clustering methods, like `pam`, or `kmeans`.

for partition evaluation: package `{clusterSim}` give several function to calculate the index to evaluate the clustering quality. Another package `{NbClust}` also calculate so many as 30 index to evaluate the combination of "distance", "clustering" and "number of clusters". However, this package partition the hierarchical tree using `{cutree}`, which is not suitable for nested clustering structure. Another method provided by `{dynamicTreeCut}` give reasonable results.

for cluster number determination: will added later.

Answer (score 0):

Cluster data for which you have class labels, and use the RAND index to measure cluster quality.

50 such datasets are at the UCR time series archive

This paper does something similar
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/ClusteringTimeSeriesUsingUnsupervised-Shapelets.pdf